# Store input from JTextField in Variable

Tags: java

I have been trying to use the input stored in the JTextField for computation, but can't seem to have it actually stored in a variable. Sure, I understand that I can use .getText(), however there is an issue accessing the text outside the actionListener.

```
          textInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    String input = textInput.getText();
                    //How do I get the 'input' variable outside this method? 
               } 
           });
```

Comment: You can use it outside this method. What is happening when you are using this ?

Comment: When I 'System.out.printlln(input)' outside the method, it doesn't work. Cannot find symbol is the message I get. I know its something simple, but I've been stuck here for literally hours. All I need to do is take the input and work with it elsewhere.

Comment: That is because 'input' is defined within the closure.

Comment: @AllenWilliams, Read Answer, for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//You defined input inside method that is why you can't access outside the method.

```
      String input="";
 textInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                        input = textInput.getText();
                        //How do I get the 'input' variable outside this method? 
                   } 
               });
```

Apply this code.

Comment: Still not working. It says 'local variables referenced from an inner class must be final'. When I make the variable final, it tells me not to make it final.